# Secured View and SIMULATED_DATA_SHARING_CONSUMER

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-sharing

We have built a secure share using secure views. Within our primary account, we have executed simulated_data_sharing_consumer under SYSADMIN and it works great, it works great for our consumers. However, we have a need to be able to perform the action for demo purposes. When I try to execute the view using SIMULATED_DATA_SHARING_CONSUMER under a different role, we get an error that the "shared view consumer simulation requires that executing role owns the view". I have transferred ownership to the role, but still nothing. What am i missing?

Comment: It would be helpful to supply more information around the DDL used, grants applied, how the share was setup, etc.  There is not nearly enough information here for anybody to assist you.